# {message: “Make sure to call fetch to execute the query” but i’m using paginate in adonis / mode.js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

In the documentation of the query builder, says that after a query i have to make a`.fetch()` or a `.paginate()` but in this case i'm receiving:

> {message: "Make sure to call fetch to execute the query"

What i tried:

```
 async show({request}){

     const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
     const filter = request.input('filter')

     const bIds = await BookUnit
                         .query()
                         .where('book_id', request.params.id)
                         .ids() 

     const questions = await Question
                             .query()
                             .whereIn('book_unit_id', bIds)
                             .with('book_unit')


     //Filtros
     if(filter){
         if(filter.search("description") !== -1){
             let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
             questions.where('description', 'ilike', '%'+description[0]+'%')
         }
         if(filter.search('unit') !== -1){
             let unit = filter.match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)
             questions.where('unit', '=', unit[0])
         }
     }

     return await questions.paginate(page,pageSize)
```

My models:

```
class Book extends Model {

    book_units() {
        return this.hasMany("App/Models/BookUnit").select(
          "id",
          "description as unit"
        );
      }

      book_unit_questions() {
        return this.manyThrough("App/Models/BookUnit", "book_unit_questions");
      }

      user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

}

class BookUnit extends Model {

    static get table () {
        return 'book_unit'
    }

    book_unit_questions() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnitQuestion')
    }


    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

}

class BookUnitQuestion extends Model {

    static get table () {
        return 'book_unit_question'
    }

    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

    book_unit(){
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/BookUnit')
            .select('id','description', 'sequence', 'unit')
    }

    book(){
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Book')
    }

    book_unit_questions() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/BookUnit')
    }

}
```

Sorry but i can't post my migrations because i receive the message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add more details", if you can create a chat i can send

@Edit:

i tried:

```
    async show({ request }){

        const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
        const filter = request.input('filter')

        const bIds = await BookUnit
               .query()
               .where('book_id', request.params.id)
               .ids()

                if (filter) {
                    if (filter.search("description") !== -1) {
                        let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                        questions.where('description', 'ilike', '%' + description[0] + '%') //Add new condition
                    }
                    if (filter.search('unit') !== -1) {
                        let unit = filter.match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                        bIds.where('unit', '=', unit[0]) //Add new condition
                    }
                }

        const questions = Question
             .query()
             .whereIn('book_unit_id', bIds)
             .with('book_unit')



        if (filter) {
            if (filter.search("description") !== -1) {
                let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                questions.where('description', 'ilike', '%' + description[0] + '%') //Add new condition
            }
        }

        return await questions.paginate(page, pageSize) //Now query is executed

but now i have:

> bIds.where is not a function",

@Edit new tentative:

async show({ request }){

        const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
        const filter = request.input('filter')

        const bIds = await BookUnit
               .query()
               .where('book_id', request.params.id)
               .ids()

        const questions = Question
             .query()
             .with('book_unit', (builder) => {
                if(filter){
                    if (filter.search('unit') !== -1) {
                        let unit = filter.match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                        builder.where('unit', '=', unit[0]) //Add new condition
                    }
                }
            })
            .whereIn('book_unit_id', bIds)

        //Filtros
        if (filter) {
            if (filter.search("description") !== -1) {
                let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                questions.where('description', 'ilike', '%' + description[0] + '%') //Add new condition
            }
        }

        return await questions.paginate(page, pageSize) //Now query is executed
} [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Dont' find the unit but the questions continue showing in my grid...

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your migrations files + models?

Comment: @CrBast please review my edit

Answer (score 2):

You have to `fetch` or `paginate` the result of the query.

My solution is to only execute the query at the end and adding conditions one by one. Like:

```js
const page = 1
const pageSize = 2
const filter = request.input('filter')

const bIds = await BookUnit
       .query()
       .where('book_id', 2)
       .ids()

/*
Remove await -> Query is not executed yet
See below
*/
const questions = Question
     .query()
     .whereIn('book_unit_id', bIds)
     .with('book_unit')

//Filtros
if (filter) {
    if (filter.search("description") !== -1) {
        let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
        questions.where('description', 'ilike', '%' + description[0] + '%') //Add new condition
    }
    if (filter.search('unit') !== -1) {
        let unit = filter.match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)
        questions.where('unit', '=', unit[0]) //Add new condition
    }
}

return await questions.paginate(page, pageSize) //Now query is executed
```

#### Information

During my test I did not use the part with the filter. I used a simple condition. Like:

```js
questions.where('book_unit_question.description', 'like', '%1%') // Test add new condition
```

Documentation : [How to prevent Knex.js from running a query object when returning it from an async function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894123/how-to-prevent-knex-js-from-running-a-query-object-when-returning-it-from-an-asy)

Comment: The problem is the unit is not a property of questions, but is a property of bookUnit...

Comment: @CrBast can you see my edit? i try with other way but i continuos have errors

Comment: `bIds.where is not a function` -> `.ids()` return an array (like : `[1, 2]`) not full model. You cannot use `.where()` on basic array

Comment: `The problem is the unit is not a property of questions, but is a property of bookUnit` -> it might help you : https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_adding_runtime_constraints

Comment: Actually i'm using runtime contraint, but is filtering the array of book_units, so, if i don't find one unit, my questions continue showing in my grid. please see my edit.

Comment: `bIds.where('unit', '=', unit[0]) //Add new condition` is wrong -> because bIds = array []

Comment: @CrBast i'm not using where in bids. i try: .with('book_unit', (builder) => {
                    if(filter){
                        if (filter.search('unit') !== -1) {
                            let unit = filter.match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                            builder.where('unit', '=', unit[0]) //Add new condition
                        }
                    } but is cleaning only the array bookUnits and the questions continuous showing in my table

Comment: @veroneseWithS Can you please create new question for that?